# C# Searching a listBox

Tags: c#, winforms, search, listbox

I have a large amount of items in a listBox called listBox1.  I also have a textBox (textBox1) at the top.  I want to be able to type into the textBox and the listBox searches through it's item's and finds ones that contain what I am typing.

For example, say the listBox contains

"Cat"

"Dog"

"Carrot"

and "Brocolli"

If I start typing the letter C, then I want it to show both Cat and Carrot, when I type a it should keep showing them both, but when I add an r it should remove Cat from the list.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Winforms? WPF? Something else? `TextBox` and `ListBox` are not part of pure C#...

Comment: WinForms, sorry I should of stated this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter the listbox. Try this:

```
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items.AddRange(new string[] {"Cat", "Dog", "Carrots", "Brocolli"});

        foreach (string str in items) 
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(str); 
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string str in items) 
        {
            if (str.StartsWith(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are not going to use AddRange you should be using BeginUpdate/EndUpdate to prohibit unneeded drawing

Comment: I like this **a lot**.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an pretty good example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Components/UseanAutocompleteComboBox.htm

Comment: -1 While similar this is a ComboBox; the OP has a ListBox coupled with a TextBox. Assuming the OP is going for something similar to filter as you type behavior ala the ICollectionView.Filter

Answer (score 1):

Rudimentary example; however this should get you started...

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<String> _animals = new List<String> { "cat", "carrot", "dog", "goat", "pig" };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(_animals.ToArray());
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String search = textBox1.Text;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(_animals.ToArray());
            }

            var items = (from a in _animals
                        where a.StartsWith(search)
                        select a).ToArray<String>();

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Clear and AddRange be bad for performance if the list is long? Or because it's all references it doesn't matter?

Comment: There would be a performance knock based on the list size at some point; however you could scale up to a decent size before a detriment in performance is noticed.

Comment: Do you know what that decent size would be?  Or whereabouts?  I expect at least a few hundred items in the list.

Comment: @LukeBerry You will be fine with a few hundred

Answer (score 1):

For getting result which the asked expects, you have to use Contains method instead StartWith method.
Like this:-

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string str in items)
        {
            if (str.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(str);
            }
        }
    }
```

I was in search for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a linq query and then databind the result.  An example of this in WPF is [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/07/filter-data-in-wpf-listbox.html), but I believe you can do the same in winforms.